# SSH permission denied for ec2 using Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-inventory

I am new to Ansible and was tring to figure out how to establish a ssh connection via ansible.

I have created an ec2 instance(Linux) and i have controlling node as my local machine(Ubuntu).

Now, I have generated and added key from my local to remote instance. I am also able to ssh by running ssh ec2-user@.

But, when doing the same using ansible command

```
ansible -i hosts all -m ping -u ec2-user
```

I am getting error as:

```
ec2-user@13.127.222.56 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ec2-user@13.127.222.56: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

My hosts file is:

```
[test]
13.127.222.56
```

Now, I am unable to figure out how to work with this further. I am missing some authentication required by ansible because this usually comes only when ssh is unable to get the key.

Comment: is the key in the default key location for ssh, ~/.ssh/id_rsa ?  And is its permissions correct?  The error message indicates that the ec2-user is correct, and the ip address is ocrrect, and the key did not successfully authenticate the user

Comment: Run `ansible` with `-vvv` and you can see the exact `ssh` command
it's using to connect to your ec2 instance. This will often help
identify the problem.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Yes it was a permission issue only. It was a minor mistake. changing the permissions worked out. turned out ansible was unable to access the id_rsa file. Thanks a lot !!